# Why does <!DOCTYPE> stop javascript from creating iFrames?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, doctype

My website uses Javascript to create iframes, and I only realised now that its almost complete that I never set a doctype for the page.

For some reason, the doctype tag, no matter which doctype i use, causes my popup iframes to stop working.

I have no idea why this is happening, but it could be something to do with my javascript (http://www.dosed.co.uk/assets/script.js).

the page (not yet quite finished) is here:
http://www.dosed.co.uk

I'm sorry that I can't be any more specific about the problem! It simply works fine without `<!DOCTYPE>` but not with it!?

Comment: Which doctype do you want, specificity? Is your HTML [valid under that doctype](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.dosed.co.uk%2FindexDEVELOPMENT.html&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=HTML5&group=0&user-agent=W3C_Validator%2F1.3+http%3A%2F%2Fvalidator.w3.org%2Fservices)? Do you get any error messages? Does this happen for all browsers?

Comment: You mean `<!DOCTYPE html>`?

Comment: Ideally i'd like to use the html5 `<!DOCTYPE html>` tag, but am happy with anything that works! I don't get any error messages, it just stops working.

Comment: Did you check the browser's error console (press F12)?

Comment: i hadn't - but have now checked it and it doesn't reveal anything...

Comment: I've still not worked this out, doesn't seem to make any sense. Can anyone tell me how a browser responds to a page without the `<!DOCTYPE>` tag? Surely the 'default' doctype would be html5 in an up-to-date browser now?

Comment: @MikeHarvey, the absence of a doctype doesn't mean "use the default doctype", it means "this document is a couple of decades out of date" because doctypes have been required in practically every version of HTML.  Browsers will use a backwards compatibility mode called "quirks mode" to render your documents that behaves quite differently to modern documents in several ways.

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a Doctype, browsers emulate the bugs of older browsers. These bugs include misfeatures such as treating a number as a length with a pixel unit when assigned to CSS properties that accept lengths (such as `ifrm.style.width=x+20;`).

Comment: Brilliant, i've added `+"px"` to where it was missing in my javascript  and now its working fine, thanks Quentin.

Answer (score 0):

`<!doctype html>`, for HTML5, does not cause problems with `<iframe>`s. `<iframe>` is in the HTML5 spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#the-iframe-element
When no `doctype` is specified, the browser assumes the page is very old, and won't work as HTML5.